# Question about the intersection of two arithmetic progressions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $\mathbb N^+=\{1,2,3,...\}$. Let $S_1  \subseteq \mathbb N^+$ and $S_2 \subseteq \mathbb N^+$ be two arithmetic progressions with the respective first terms $a_1$ and $b_1$ and respective distances $d_1$ and $d_2$.

Let's say $a_1 \le d_1$ and $b_1\le d_2$. Let $S_3$ be the non-empty intersection of $S_1$ and $S_2$ with first term $c_1$ and common distance $d'$. Does this mean that $c_1 \le d'$?

I thought of a proof. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, we know that $S_3$ is an arithmetic progression and that $d'$ is the LCM of $d_1$ and $d_2$. Let $\{p_1, p_2,...,p_n\}$ be the collection of all terms in $S_1$ such that $p_i\le d'$. Let $\{q_1, q_2,...,q_n\}$ be the collection of all terms in $S_2$ such that $q_i\le d'$. Assume for reductio that $c_1 >d'$. Let $m = c_1 \bmod d'$. Since $c_1$ is the first term of $S_3$, this means that $c_1$ appears in both $S_1$ and $S_2$. If $m=0$, then $c_1$ is a multiple of $d'$, which in turn means that it is a multiple of $d_1$ and $d_2$. It stands to reason that $S_1$ is an arithmetic progression of multiples of $d_1$ and $S_2$ of $d_2$. But this means that $c_1$ is the LCM of $d_1$ and $d_2$, i.e. $c_1 = d'$. Contradiction. So, $m \ne 0$.

Assume now that $m > 0$. It must be the case that $m \in \{p_1, p_2,...,p_n\}$. This is because $m$ needs to be a term in $S_1$ in order for $c_1$ to appear later in the sequence. And since $m \le d'$, $m \in \{p_1, p_2,...,p_n\}$. For the same reason, $m \in \{q_1, q_2,...,q_n\}$. But if this is the case, then $m$ is the first term of $S_3$, i.e. $m = c_1$. Contradiction as $m \le d'$. So, it must be the case that $c_1 \le d'$.

Is this proof correct?